# Переустановка виндодвс (сохранить boot сектор)

Tags: linux, windows, grub, dual-boot

Установлены Window + Linux

Задумываюсь о переустановке Windows. При этом, понятно, затрётся загрузочный сектор, и придётся его восстанавливать с диска Линукса. Последнее сопряжено с трудностями, поскольку диск у меня довольно древней версии, наверно ещё 17, а сейчас стоит 27. В последний раз, когда я обновил Линукс с 17 до 19, а потом переставил Виндовс, восстановить нормальную загрузку последнего было целой проблемой, связанной с тем, что штатный режим восстанавливал загрузчик для 17, а 19 не хотела грузиться из-за разной версии vmlinuz...

Вопрос состоит в том: как можно сделать переустановку, чтобы не затронуть загрузчик Линукс?

Answer (score 1):

Интересный вопрос) На мой взгляд - никак, т. к. на работе были случаи, что Windows 10 после обновление (именно обновления) мог переписать загрузочный сектор. Как вариант (исходя из моего опыта):

1. Переустановить Windows
2. Загрузиться при помощи bootUSB используемого
   линукса
3. Сделать chroot в вашу линукс систему
4. Переустановить загрузочник ([http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/восстановление_grub](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_grub))

Comment: Если у Вас есть Live-CD или Live-Flash, дистрибутива, который у Вас установлен, то в меню загрузки с этого носителя должен быть пункт "Восстановить загрузчик Grub"

Comment: Нету диска той версии. Об этом написаны выше "Последнее сопряжено с трудностями, поскольку диск у меня довольно древней версии, наверно ещё 17, а сейчас стоит 27."

Comment: @yuchimenko-igor, возможно мы друг друга не поняли: 
как уже было написано мной ранее - "На мой взгляд - никак" и в последующем описал один из самых простых вариантов решения. Если нет диска, но имеется свободный флеш-накопитель и возможность скачать дистрибутив текущей версии, то не вижу никаких проблем. Как вариант - после переустановки попробовать установить GRUB из старой версии, а при последующей загрузке обновиться до более новой. Но это если в старой есть GRUB2 и, прежде использовать такой вариант, я бы съэмулировал данную ситуацию на виртуальной машине.

Comment: Я понял. Просто не хотелось заниматься скачиванием и восстановлением.
Мой комментарий был к @Sergey, а не к вам.